# How to remove spaces between special characters

Tags: ruby, string

I have a requirement to remove spaces between special characters. I have a string:

```
abc = "test = > @ Stack overflow"
```

I want a string like this:

```
abc = "test=>@Stack overflow"
```

so that only spaces between, before, or after are removed. failed to create a proper regular expression or method for that. Any hint or idea?

Comment: What do you consider a special character?

Comment: everything apart from digit and character. It's correctly mentioned by @stribizhev below.

Comment: @Arup confused, since I'm answering all the regex question..

Comment: @AvinashRaj please check the answer by below.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh Why?

Comment: for the correct REGEX for ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
abc = "test = > @ Stack overflow"
puts abc.gsub(/\s*([^\s\p{L}\p{N}])\s*/, "\\1")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/PQ8c6M), result: `test=>@Stack overflow`.

The capturing group is necessary to restore the captured "special" character.

The `[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]` stands for *a non-whitespace, non-letter and non-digit* character.

Comment: Readers: `"\\1"` can alternatively be written `'\1'`.